# Padding pixels in YUV video with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a yuv video and I want to do some padding in every frame.
in this case, I have a column number for example X and i want to copy pixels of column X to column X-1 and column X+1.

How can I do this with FFmpeg?

Before padding:

[image: before padding]

After padding:

[image: after padding]

Comment: Columns or rows? The images show columns being duplicated. Is it the same column every frame?

Comment: @gyan. oops! sorry. I meant the columns.